# Redirecting stdout of EOF

Tags: shell, sh

I want to redirect the error and output streams to `/dev/null` and I used `2>&1 /dev/null` in my script file (below) but I am getting error as

```
"UPDATE 1
UPDATE 1
UPDATE 1
UPDATE 1
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "EOF"
LINE 1: EOF 2>&1 /dev/null"        ^
```

How to redirect stdout?

## File:

```
psql -h xx.xx.xx.xx -U postgres -d dbname 

<<

update rhq_alert_condition set threshold = $critical_threshold  where alert_definition_id = $critical_id;
update rhq_alert_condition set threshold = $critical_threshold  where alert_definition_id = $critical_recovery_id;
update rhq_alert_condition set threshold = $warning_threshold  where alert_definition_id = $warning_id;
update rhq_alert_condition set threshold = $warning_threshold  where alert_definition_id = $warning_recovery_id;

EOF

2>&1 /dev/null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The errors messages you get are due to syntax errors in your script.

The here-document that you appear to be using needs to be started with `<<EOF` rather than with just `<<`:

```
psql -h xx.xx.xx.xx -U postgres -d dbname <<EOF
update rhq_alert_condition set threshold = $critical_threshold  where alert_definition_id = $critical_id;
update rhq_alert_condition set threshold = $critical_threshold  where alert_definition_id = $critical_recovery_id;
update rhq_alert_condition set threshold = $warning_threshold  where alert_definition_id = $warning_id;
update rhq_alert_condition set threshold = $warning_threshold  where alert_definition_id = $warning_recovery_id;
EOF
```

To redirect the output from this to a file:

```
psql -h xx.xx.xx.xx -U postgres -d dbname >outfile <<EOF
update rhq_alert_condition set threshold = $critical_threshold  where alert_definition_id = $critical_id;
update rhq_alert_condition set threshold = $critical_threshold  where alert_definition_id = $critical_recovery_id;
update rhq_alert_condition set threshold = $warning_threshold  where alert_definition_id = $warning_id;
update rhq_alert_condition set threshold = $warning_threshold  where alert_definition_id = $warning_recovery_id;
EOF
```

To also redirect the error stream to the same file:

```
psql -h xx.xx.xx.xx -U postgres -d dbname >outfile 2>&1 <<EOF
update rhq_alert_condition set threshold = $critical_threshold  where alert_definition_id = $critical_id;
update rhq_alert_condition set threshold = $critical_threshold  where alert_definition_id = $critical_recovery_id;
update rhq_alert_condition set threshold = $warning_threshold  where alert_definition_id = $warning_id;
update rhq_alert_condition set threshold = $warning_threshold  where alert_definition_id = $warning_recovery_id;
EOF
```

To have the error stream go to `/dev/null`, use `2>/dev/null` instead.

To have both streams go to the bit-bucket, use `>/dev/null 2>&1`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

> command > /dev/null 2>&1

Answer (score 0):

I guess this `bash` example does what the author asked about:

```sh
gnuplot -p << EOF > /dev/null 2>/dev/null
plot 'file.dat'
EOF
```

I called `gnuplot` and not `psql`, but the idea about EOF and redirecting is the same.